# asp.net mvc: how do I use the entity framework to autoupdate the underlying DB when I make a change to the model in code?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am getting a feel for ASP.NET MVC 4. I have successfully created a simple CRUD application using scaffolding/code generation. I am connected to a DB on sql server via a connection string. Now I have updated the model class that I used to initially create the code. How do I get this to update the model in the underlying project/add the new field in the database?

I use linq-to-sql all the time for winforms applications so I'm used to changing a table in SQL server and then dragging the modified table from the solution explorer onto the datacontext. What is the analog in asp.net mvc 4? I don't see a datacontext class (in a data folder) in the solution explorer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have the appropriate `project` selected in the Default Project dropdown in the `Package Manager Console`

- Run the **Enable-Migrations** command in *Package Manager Console*
- **Add-Migration** will scaffold the next migration based on changes you
  have made to your model since the last migration was created
- **Update-Database** will apply any pending migrations to the database

Comment: Just FYI, if you have more than one startup project in your solution (or your startup project is *not* the project that has your migrations, you'll need to specify the project that contains the migrations. The easiest way to do this is to actually change the "Default project" dropdown to that project in the package manager console.